# CSS Grid not fitting all columns

Tags: css, css-grid

When trying to position 2 elements in a css grid, the second overflows to the next row even though there is enough column space for it to fit. As seen in photo:
[image]

CSS:

```
.grid-parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}

.map {
  grid-column: 5 / -1;
}

.nav-panel-container {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when your source order doesn't match your visual / grid order.

Adding

```
.grid-parent { grid-auto-flow: column dense; }
```

should fix the problem.

See this example:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  border: 5px dashed #999;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 170px;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #999;
}

.dense {
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sample">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li style="grid-column-start: 5;">5</li>
  <li style="grid-column-start: 4;">4</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" onclick="sample.classList.toggle('dense')">Toggle grid-auto-flow: column dense</button>
```